# WPF DataGrid in the child window is not getting data-bound somehow

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have classes like these: (sorry lengthy question)

```
public class BaselineEntity
{
    public List<RecComparisionData> ComparisionData { get; set; }
}

public class RecComparisionData
{
    public string FieldCaption { get; set; }
    public string ColumnValue { get; set; }
    public string BaselineValue { get; set; }

    public string Flag 
    {
        get 
        { 
            return ColumnValue == BaselineValue ? "same" : "different";
        }
    }
}
```

I instantiate and call the showDialog of a new window from the Main window.
Here is the code in the main window where I do that.

```
private void compareBtnClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _enty_toCompare = new BaselineEntity
                      {
                         ComparisionData = new List<RecComparisionData>();
                      };

    var bla = new RecComparisionData
              {
                  FieldCaption = "Yada yada 1",
                  ColumnValue = "123", 
                  BaselineValue = "234"
              }
    _enty_toCompare.ComparisionData.Add(bla);

    // add a few more such blas..

    // instantiating and opening a new window as a ddialog
    RecComparer compWindow = new RecComparer(_enty_toCompare);
    compWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

The RecComparer code behind is something like this:

```
public partial class RecComparer : Window
{
    private BaselineEntity _blEnty;
    private List<RecComparisionData> _compData;

    public RecComparer(BaselineEntity blEnty)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _blEnty = blEnty;

        _compData = blEnty.ComparisionData;

        // this is a datagrid, whose xaml is cited below
        ComparisionDataGrid.ItemsSource = _compData;
    }
}
```

The RecComparer window has a DataGrid's XAML is this:

```
<DataGrid Name="ComparisionDataGrid" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding _compData, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field" Binding="{Binding FieldCaption}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding ColumnValue}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Baseline Value" Binding="{Binding BaselineValue}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Flag" Binding="{Binding Flag}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I could see the data in _compData while debugging, but nothing shows up in the DataGrid. Somehow the binding is not happeing (not again!!).. and I have to post this lengthy question because I could find nothing that helped after looking for hours.. :(

Any suggestions or help is appreciated..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand DataContext here looks like its null. You'll also have to ensure your properties are public so they can be bound. (Private properties cannot be databound). I also suggest renaming your properties to somthing more publicy :).

Because its DataBound you dont need to set the ItemsSource in the code behind either.

Try this:

```
public partial class RecComparer : Window
{
    public BaselineEntity _blEnty{get;set}
    public List<RecComparisionData> _compData {get;set}

    public RecComparer(BaselineEntity blEnty)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        _blEnty = blEnty;

        _compData = blEnty.ComparisionData;

        // this is a datagrid, whose xaml is cited below

        //ComparisionDataGrid.ItemsSource = _compData;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just made all the properties public and put getters and setters on them. What happens now (and I think it happened before as well) is that the data shows up in the datagrid for a fraction of a second and vanishes without a trace.. :(

Comment: Found it! I removed the two-way binding for the datagrid (since I didn't implement the class with INotifyTheView or something interface). I don't need 2-way binding here cuz, it's just a comparer window. That solved..
Thanks Ashesh. I'll findout about "Snoop" to check the dataContext. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Make '_compData' in RecComparer  as public. Change it to property

```
public List<RecComparisionData> CompData{get;set;}
```

Databinding works with Public properties.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I made all the properties that are bound public, and to have getters and setters. The data in the datagrid shows up for a fraction of a second and vanishes..